# Logback: how to log only errors to file

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I've been reading the logback manual for 2 hours and still can't figure how to do what I need.

It is as simple as the title says: I want to log only the errors to a file, and the other levels (including ERROR) to console.

This is the root section of my logcat.xml file:

```
    <root level="TRACE" >
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_APPENDER" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER" />
    </root>
```

The problem with this configuration is that it logs every level >= TRACE to both appenders.

I could let the root with only console, and define a file logger:

```
    <logger name='file_logger' level='ERROR' >
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER" />
    </logger>
```

But then I'd have to call the normal logger like this:

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientClass.class);
```

And the file logger like this:

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger("file_logger");
```

I don't wan't to choose the logger for each class. I just want to get the root logger from the factory using the class as parameter, and have it do the correct thing depending on the level.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create 2 different ROOT loggers with logback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827633/how-to-create-2-different-root-loggers-with-logback)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Put this into your file appender definition:

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
    <level>ERROR</level>
</filter>
```

The `ThresholdFilter` is in `logback-classic.jar`.

Comment: Nice. I'm using [logback for android](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android) and seems to work too.

Comment: This can also help; XSD for logback.xml. That can help you with configuration variables.
https://github.com/enricopulatzo/logback-XSD

Comment: Thanks, you approach worked. However, this defeats the whole purpose of `level` attribute on the `root` tag, since this its primary feature - determine log level of  the appender.

Answer (score 8):

I don't understand why wrong answer here is upvoted.
The guy wants ONLY error messages in his file.

Here is the correct answer:

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
  <level>ERROR</level>
  <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
  <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
</filter>
```

Reference:
https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#levelFilter

Comment: It is because the solution upvoted uses ThresholdFilter that filters everything bellow error.

Comment: I understand that. I don't understand how does it address the problem stated by the author. Author wants to log ONLY errors into the file.

Comment: Good point.  The rest of us assumed he wanted "error and above" :) update: it appears in logback land ERROR is the highest level, unlike log4j that has "fatal" go figure...http://logback.qos.ch/manual/architecture.html#basic_selection

Comment: I think the opposite of this is what the answer should be. ACCEPT and DENY should exchange their places

Comment: There are developers that understand the problem behind a description and there are othrs that take things literally. It's obvious that the op wanted to have his error messages persisted. So if there would be a FATAL level, it's pretty clear that these should go into that logfile too. That's the whole point of log _levels_. Funny conversation later: "Fatal messages? Nooo, we can't see them any more - you wanted to persist only errors" :)

Answer (score 2):

Refer below code:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
            <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>ACCEPT</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```