# Logback: log only ERROR from log4j to file

Tags: java, logback

I have tried the solution from [Logback: how to log only errors to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689223/logback-how-to-log-only-errors-to-file)
but it doesn't work for me:
What can be wrong with my logback.xml file?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
     <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />


    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>ALL.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

            <fileNamePattern>ALL.%d{yyyy-ww}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-ERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>ERROR.log</file>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

            <fileNamePattern>ERROR.%d{yyyy-ww}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Then to files and console goes only ERRORs.
Is it because I log the errors with log4j?

Comment: you showed us only the `FILE-ERROR` appender, but the `root` logger refers to `STDOUT` and `FILE` appenders; can you share the full `logback.xml`?

Comment: I have added full xml

Comment: Thanks! Now, to me it looks like it should work. Could you please clarify what do you mean by _“I log the errors with log4j”_?

Comment: It is Spring application in which I log INFO errors using log4j `private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyExample.class);` Maybe I should write 2 roots?

Comment: @sainaen: Oh I have change the order of the roots (first ERROR) and now it works... strange

Comment: hmm. yeah, that may cause issues, as I understand it. but if changing the order helped, then it’s a bit simpler to solve, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this part is what causes the issue:

```xml
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" />
    </root>
```

Here, we first set the level on `root` logger to `INFO`, attach two appenders to it, but then *reassign* the level to be `ERROR` and attach another appender.

Since you set the filter on `FILE-ERROR` appender, there’s no need to change the `root`’s level and you can attach all the appenders at once:

```xml
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" />
    </root>
```