# Spring Boot JDBC Template SQL Log

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, spring-jdbc

I am trying log SQL queries with params for Spring Boot JDBC but it is not printing  the details in log.I am using Spring Boot 1.5.8 version.Please help me to solve this.

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=url
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=debug

spring.datasource.type = com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=2
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public class DataRepository {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataRepository.class);

    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public Data findDataObjet() throws Exception {

        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("id1", "mike");
        parameters.put("id2", new Long(1));

        String sqlString = "select * from table1 where id1 = ":id" and id2 = :id2";
        log.info("Query:" + sqlString);//this log is printing

        Data extObj = jdbcTemplate.query(sqlString, parameters, (rs) -> {
            if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
                Data innerObj = new Data();
                innerObj.setName(rs.getString("name"));             
                return innerObj;
            } else {
                log.info("No records found:"+rs);
                return null;
            }
        });

        return extObj;

    }
}
```

**logback-spring.xml:**

```
<appender name="dailyRollingFileAppender"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <FileNamePattern>${logsPath}DATA%d{MMddyyyy}.log
        </FileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>4</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level
            %logger{35}-%msg %n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFileAppender" />
</root>
```

Comment: Is this `else {log.info("No records found:"+rs);return null; }` ever executed  ?

Comment: @CrazySabbath yes it is printing in the logs.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827633/how-to-create-2-different-root-loggers-with-logback

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try

```
log4j.category.org.springframework.jdbc.core = TRACE
```

The above statement will print SQL queries with inbound parameters as well.

Incase you need to log only the query use the following

```
log4j.category.org.springframework.jdbc.core = DEBUG
```

You can enable in your logback file with the following

```
<logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
  <level value="debug" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils">
  <level value="debug" />
</logger>
```

**Update :** For Springboot 2.x , it would be

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=TRACE
```

Thanks zhuguowei!

Comment: I created one more question related to this please answer if you can thanks.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146167/setting-sql-statement-parameter-value-column-index-1-parameter-value-name-v

Comment: this way not work for spring boot 2.1.4 . Should be this: `logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=TRACE`

Comment: @zhuguowei  I do not see any sql statements traced in the console, placed this in the application.yml file logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core: TRACE

Comment: which file name should this go in ? we are using maven logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=TRACE.

Answer (score 9):

Adding the following to your properties file also works:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core = TRACE
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Spring-Boot 2.1.x you have to set the property:
`logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=TRACE` to log the statement and the parameters.

Answer (score -3):

try those statement in application properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```